# how to get the name field of a record when given the id

Tags: eclipse, salesforce, apex-code, soql

I have a query:

```
SELECT Id, recordtypeid  FROM myObject__c
```

but instead of returning the recordtype id, i want to return the recordtype name. How do i do that?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! please read [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Id, RecordType.Name from myObject__c

[image]

Comment: that just returns the string "recordtype'- not the actual rt

Comment: that's a bug in whatever tool you're using.

Comment: really?  I'm using eclipse IDE (queried the schema) and tried in  the explorer. got the same result....

Comment: the IDE doesn't support SOQL-R queries correctly. I added an example response using SoqlX

Comment: It works good, just click on the string "RecordType" and in a popup window you will see the record type name (i mean in eclipse).

Comment: @Superfell - that's a good piece of knowledge to have. thanks.... I don't know about SoqlX- I'll take a look into it. Thanks :)